How to compare float numbers in an if conditional in BASH?
My code is:
#!/bin/bash
rm N_Matrix.csv
Lineas=`wc -l $1| awk '{print $1}'`
for (( i = 1 ; i <= Lineas ; i++ ));
do
    Numer_1=`awk -vvar=$i 'NR==var' $1`
    for (( j = 1 ; j <= Lineas ; j++ ));
    do
        Numer_2=`awk -vvar=$j 'NR==var' $1`
        if (( ${Numer_1} -ge ${Numer_2} )); 
        then
            Descriptor=`echo "(($Numer_1)/($Numer_2))" | bc -l`
        else
            Descriptor=`echo "(($Numer_2)/($Numer_1))" | bc -l`
        fi
        echo $Descriptor >> $i.txt
    done
done

paste {1..29}.txt > N_Matrix.csv
rm *.txt

The content of my working file is:
10.1234567
20.1234567
30.1234567
40.1234567
15.1234567
25.1234567
35.1234567
45.1234567

I have an error on the if conditional and I have tried all possible combinations. But still I cannot see what the mistake is.
I get line 10: ((: 45.1234567 -ge 45.1234567 : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".1234567 -ge 45.1234567 ")

I'd recommend https://www.shellcheck.net/ to see the most common mistakes

-ge is not an operator for the ((...)) command.

The whole point of ((...)) is that you can simply use >= instead of legacy test syntax.

I tried >=. but still I got the same error.

Short answer: You don't. Use a language which can do floats, for instance zsh or bc.

I’m voting to close this question because the OP didn't run their code through http://shellcheck.net as directed by the [tag:bash] tag.

please update the question with ... a) a textual description of what you're trying to do and b) the expected results (contents of N_Matrix.csv)

while you may have an answer to the syntax issue you may want to reconsider a rewrite of this entire process; repeatedly calling awk and bc within a pair of bash loops is going to have terrible performance; instead you can probably replace the entire current bash script with a single awk script which is going to provide a huge boost in performance (and keep in mind awk can handle float numbers)

The error is clearly indicated: there is invalid syntax line 10
        if (( ${Numer_1} -ge ${Numer_2} )); 

I see three problems:

-ge is for operator [[ ... ]] and [ ... ] use (( ... >= ... )) instead
(( ... )) only support integer number. This is the main problem  with your script
in (( ... )), variable should not use dollar (but it still works with it)

It should work if you use bc to compare numbers
        result=$(bc -l <<< "${Numer_1} >= ${Numer_2}") # bc will print 1 if condition is true
        if [[ "${result}" == 1 ]] # check that bc printed 1


That puts a bandaid on it but the whole shell script should be replaces with a single call to awk.
